# Eclipse Instantly detect external file change

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, webstorm, bndtools

I am using eclipse bndtools plugin **to develop OSGi based web application**. 
I am using Eclipse IDE (because of bndtools) and Jetbrain Webstorm IDE to edit the html/css/js files.

When I change files in eclipse, the bndtools refresh the bundle and I can see the changes immediately, but when I edit files using Webstorm I need to refresh the project in eclipse in order to see the result.

NOTE: I have enabled the Eclipse workspace setting **Windows > Preferences > General > Workspace > Refresh using native hooks or polling and Refresh on access**
. But this will only enable eclipse to detect changes when I access the files in eclipse.

To speed up my development, I don't want to refresh the project using eclipse on every changes I make in Webstorm. I am asking if there is a way to avoid it.

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse has editors for html/css/js files. Why not just stick to one IDE?

Comment: I use angular2 to build my client side, webstorm provide intelligent auto-completion and ...

Comment: in WebStorm,  try turning 'Safe write' option ( Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Use "safe write" (save changes to temporary file first)) off - does it make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

The option "Refresh using native hooks or polling and Refresh on access" just do what you are asking for.
The option "Refresh on access" only refresh the file when you access it (when opening the file, or if the file is open in an editor).
Tested in Eclipse Photon.